# Quick counting with linked Django Models

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I've got a stack of Models something like this (I'm typing it out in relative shorthand):

```
class User:
    pass


class ItemList:
    pass


# A User can have more than one ItemList
# An ItemList can have more than one User
# Classic M2M

class ItemListOwnership:
    user = fk(User)
    itemlist = fk(ItemList)


# An ItemList has multiple Items

class Item:
    itemlist = fk(ItemList)
```

What I want to do is display a simple count of how many items a given user (or existing queryset of users) have on their various lists. **I need to count across the M2M divide.**

That's where I'm stuck. I'm happy with a pure SQL method if that's the only thing that works but I really don't want to get into a situation where I'm issuing *n + 1* queries per user (where n is the number of lists a user has) just for a count...

Edit: I'm not using a "real" `models.ManyToMany(..)` relationship because I define additional things in `ItemListOwnership` that describe the relationship slightly better. If it's a killer, I can probably move this metadata elsewhere and get rid of `ItemListOwnership` and stick a m2m in `ItemList`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, defining extra fields in a linking table is what the `through` functionality of `ManyToManyField` is for. So, keep your ItemListOwnership table with its FKs, but add a `userlist=ManyToMany('User', through='ItemListOwnership')` to `UserList`.

Once you've done this, you can easily count the number of items for each user by using annotate:

```
from django.db.models import Count
User.objects.all().annotate(item_count=Count('userlist__item'))
```

Now each user has an `item_count` attribute which is the number of items they have.